# BATCH Variable Input to Math Subtraction

Tags: batch-file

Very simple question.
I am creating a simple texted based game in batch. It is about you are a pilot for the airline and you need to stop it from crashing into a random variable. Before you "take off" you need to edit your programming terminal and tell it your fuel. The fuel is marked with %fuel%. So when you are in the air. Your Turn will cost you 1000L of Fuel so if I input 54000 i will have 54 turns to get the plane safely landed. The code for the fuel input and display are here I just need the code to have the %fuel% - 1000

```
:fuel
cls
color c
echo ----------------------------------------
echo       FUEL NEEDED FOR FLIGHT
echo ----------------------------------------
echo Awnser in Litres Please
echo eg 54000 
echo -----------------------------------------
set /p fuel=""
echo -----------------------------------------
echo          Is this Correct Y/N
echo -----------------------------------------
set /p c4=""
if /I "%c4%" EQU "Y" goto :d4
if /I "%c4%" EQU "N" goto :fuel
goto :fuel
:d4
color a
cls
echo ---------------------------------------
echo Flight Navigation System
echo %dep% to %arr%
echo Heading %heading% Degrees
echo ----------------------------------------
echo Captain - %captain%
echo 1st Officer - %officera% 
echo 2nd Officer - %officerb%
echo Head Flight Attenedent - %hfa%
echo ----------------------------------------
echo FUEL - %fuel% Litres Remaining
echo ----------------------------------------
pause
```

Comment: I suggest [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/), a great reference of batch commands. You need the [set /a](https://ss64.com/nt/set.html) command.

Answer (score 0):

Use "Set /a fuel-=1000". If you are using XP you might need to do "Set /a fuel= %fuel%-1000"